# Should i call my Range explicitly when i'm referring to the sheet i'm coding in?

Tags: excel, vba

My program retrieves data from an excel file (call it workbook1) and places it in my own (workbook2). I'm placing the data in the sheet in workbook2 where the majority of my code is written.

Is there a better way to call the worksheet explicitly if your calling the sheet where the code is written other than the way i'm coding below?

workbook2.sheets("sheet1").cells(1,1) = workbook1.sheets(sheetname).cells(2,2)

Comment: If it is in the worksheet module you can use `Me.Cells(...`

Comment: But one thing you may want to investigate is either create object variable to hold the sheet or use `With`.  either of these approaches will limit the number of times it is required to type out the full parent.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following to access the same sheet on which you are coding:

```
ActiveSheet.Cells(2,2)
```